# git in IntelliJ IDEA without sacrificing netbeans history feature

Tags: git, intellij-idea, netbeans, version-control, diff

Below is the image that shows the feature in Netbeans , where the file changes can be compared by doing the right click and changes can be undone.

[[image: image]]

It is the feature that help a lot. I want to Switch to IntelliJ, but i could not find a similar feature in it, if it is available how to get to this feature in IntelliJ?

For clarification, in NetBeans, the fucnctionality is inLine and there is no need to click any extra page as shown below.

[[image: image]]

Comment: IDEA has the same markers on the left gutter. Click on them and you'll get similar options.

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark the answer (√ symbol on the left of the answer). And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the similar feature is also available for IntelliJ IDEA. You can also view the changes and revert (undo) the changes.

In the Local Changes window, there list the changed file(s), you can show diff for a changed file by selecting **Show Diff**, or you can **preview diff** in the same window.

[image]
[image]

To revert (undo) the changes, you can click revert.

[image]

Comment: The OP was describing the inline change markers in the editor. IDEA has those, too. (I even think that IDEA had them first.)

Answer (score 0):

IDEA change markers work exactly the same way:

[image: IDEA Change markers]

For that to work, you must have configured your git (or other VCS) repository correctly in File->Settings->Version Control